# Django import settings error

Tags: python, django

I have the following script for scraping a webform:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
Python script for searching firms on http://www.adviserinfo.sec.gov/IAPD/Content/Search/iapd_Search.aspx

Assumes that the input Excel file is in the same directory as this script.
"""

import os
import re
import sys
import django
import mechanize

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from xlrd import open_workbook

XLSX_FILE = 'Legal Names.xlsx'
IAPD_URL = 'http://www.adviserinfo.sec.gov/IAPD/Content/Search/iapd_Search.aspx'

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sys.path.append(os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'scraper/')))
sys.path.append(os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'scraper/scraper/')))

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
django.setup()

from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from custom_scraper.models import *
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def legal_names(file=XLSX_FILE):
    '''
    Read in legal names from the excel spreadsheet with the assumption
    that names to be searched for are in column 1. Skip row 1 header
    '''
    wb = open_workbook(file)
    s = wb.sheets()[0]

    col = 1
    for row in range(s.nrows)[1:]:
        name = s.cell(row, col).value
        if type(name) == int:
            continue

        yield name

class IapdScraper(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.br = mechanize.Browser()
        self.br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 
                               'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.63 Safari/535.7')]


    def scrape(self, q):
        '''
        Search for a Firm in the IAPD database by name
        '''
        def select_form(form):
            return form.attrs.get('id', None) == 'aspnetForm'

        try:
            firm = IapdFirm.objects.get(query_name=q)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            firm = IapdFirm(query_name=q)
            firm.save()
        else:
            if firm.checked:
                return

        self.br.open(IAPD_URL)
        self.br.select_form(predicate=select_form)
        self.br.form['ctl00$cphMainContent$ucUnifiedSearch$rdoSearchBy'] = ['rdoOrg']
        self.br.submit()

        self.br.select_form(predicate=select_form)
        self.br.form['ctl00$cphMainContent$ucUnifiedSearch$txtFirm'] = q.encode('utf8')
        self.br.submit()

        s = BeautifulSoup(self.br.response().read())
        r = re.compile(r'^ctl\d+_cphMainContent_grOrgResults$')
        t = s.find('table', id=r)

        if not t: # Not found
            print 'Not Found'
            firm.checked = True
            firm.save()
            return 

        tr = t.findAll('tr', recursive=False)
        tr = tr[2:-1] # Skip records-per-page header/footer and title header

        for row in tr:
            td = row.findAll('td', recursive=False)

            firm.legal_name = td[0].b.text.strip()
            firm.other_name = td[1].text.strip()
            firm.sec_number = td[2].text.strip()
            firm.address = td[3].text.strip()
            firm.checked = True
            firm.save()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scraper = IapdScraper()

    for name in legal_names():
        print '\nq=%s' % name
        scraper.scrape(q=name)
```

When I run the script in my `venv`, however, I get the following error:

```
c:\Users\bal2155\venv\Scripts>scraper.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bal2155\venv\Scripts\scraper.py", line 26, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 20, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 46, in __ge
tattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 42, in _set
up
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 98, in __in
it__
    % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
ImportError: Could not import settings 'settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there a
n import error in the settings file?): No module named settings
```

I have a inkling that this has to do either with how I've set up the `venv` or how I downloaded `django`. I've checked the documentation for the latter and I'm not sure what the `myproject.settings` extension means. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to add the python modules to the path. Check your manage.py, the required ones are defined there normally

Comment: Did you run [startproject](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#startproject-projectname-destination)? That should create a settings file for you. I would also recommend the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/).

Comment: I ran startproject to the path where the script is located. I'm getting another error, but smaller this time: `C:\Users\bal2155\mysite\venv\Scripts\myproject>scraper.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bal2155\mysite\venv\Scripts\myproject\scraper.py", line 29, in
<module>
    from custom_scraper.models import *
ImportError: No module named custom_scraper.models`